# finding locations of a set of elements in a matrix - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix A .
I want to find all the unique elements is A so:
b = unique(A);  will give array of all the unique elements in A.

I want to find the locations of these elements in A. To be precise, the elements in b 
repeat themselves in A and I want to find for each element in b its **rows** in A.

How one can do that without a loop?

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
[b,m,n] = unique(A);
```

should give you all the data you need to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code which does what I think you are trying to do:

```
%Test data
A = [...
    1 2 3 4; ...
    4 5 6 7; ...
    8 1 3 4];

%Basic "unique" call
[B, ix_A, ix_B] = unique(A);

%Note that the indexes from unique can be used as follows
isequal(A(ix_A), B )   %Returns true
isequal(B(ix_B), A(:) )   %Returns true

%To find a row (and column) in A where each element in B can be found we
%just need to convert the linear indexs into row/column subscripts
[row, column] = ind2sub(size(A), ix_A);
%     Note that in general, multiple rows will contain each value from A.
%     This will always produce one of the rows (and columns), pracitcially,
%     it looks like to returns the last row containing the value.
```

Comment: You can control whether the index returned is the first or last occurrence of the value by passing 'first' or 'last' to the unique function. You should also pass 'row' if you want to find unique rows rather than unique elements.

Comment: My understanding of the question was the per-element unique value was desired, not the unique rows.  But it is a good point.  I did not know that `unique` supported the 'first' and 'last' keywords.  That's a good tip.